# I have four buttons directing to a single activity, how to findout which button caused the activity to open?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

```
Button novice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.novice);

novice.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent nov = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), gameface.class);
        startActivity(nov);
        nov.putExtra("lvl", "1");
    }
});

Button easy1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.easy);
easy1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent eas = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), gameface.class);
        startActivity(eas);
        eas.putExtra("lvl", "2");
    }
});
```

THis is my code so i tried sending data with the button press and thought of using
this

```
Intent g = getIntent();
String x = g.getStringExtra("lvl");
```

on the new activity to capture which button it was but it doesnt work.

can someone tell me whats up?

Comment: hi shiva,always first put values in Intent before passing to startActivity().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `eas.putExtra("lvl", "2");` before `startActivity(eas);`:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent eas = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), gameface.class);
    eas.putExtra("lvl", "2");
    startActivity(eas);
}
```

Also, although not mentioned in your code, make sure you compare the strings using "equals" and not `==`.

Comment: Thank you! How Stupid of me to set the stuff to send after sending the data. :P

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the Extras in the Intent before starting the Activity.

```
eas.putExtra("lvl", "2");
 startActivity(eas);
```

Answer (score 1):

They are telling you to put the eas.putExtra before calling the intent because putExtra is how you add additional data to an intent so you can pull it out in the new activity.  When you receive the intent you can pull this serialized data from the intent object and use it in your new activity.  This is how you can pass "extra" data between activities because in Android each activity is it's own little sandbox and can only operate with other activities through intents.